# testcafe-reporter-slack fails to report from reportTaskDone method at times

Tags: test-report, testcafe

I've been playing around with [testcafe-reporter-slack](https://github.com/pavelsaman/testcafe-reporter-slack).

I face the following problem. First off, all my relevant `.testcaferc.json` settings for the reporter (just minus the webhook url :)):

```json
{
    "name": "slack",
    "options": {
        "webhookUrl": "secret",
        "channel": "#testreporters",
        "username": "AlpineProOutletTestReporter",
        "loggingLevel": "SUMMARY",
        "quietMode": false
    }
}
```

When I fire up my tests (`$ testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"`), the first part of the report gets reported to my slack channel:

[image]

this works fine.

The problem is that **sometimes** the final part of the report, created by [reportTaskDone](https://github.com/pavelsaman/testcafe-reporter-slack/blob/master/src/index.js#L52), doesn't get reported to my slack channel. It's simply lost. But at other times, it does work, and I can see the whole report:

[image]

Both times, I'm using the same tests, the same command to run them. Both times, my config is the same. I also took logs:

- this log was generated when the final part was correctly reported to slack:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 't:headless:chromium' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.7
3 info using node@v14.8.0
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'pret:headless:chromium',
4 verbose run-script   't:headless:chromium',
4 verbose run-script   'postt:headless:chromium'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle @~pret:headless:chromium: @
6 info lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pavel/testing/alpine/AlpineProOutlet.Tests/node_modules/.bin:/home/pavel/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/pavel/.local/bin:/home/pavel/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin:
9 verbose lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: CWD: /home/pavel/testing/alpine/AlpineProOutlet.Tests
10 silly lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: Args: [ '-c', 'testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: Failed to exec t:headless:chromium script
13 verbose stack Error: @ t:headless:chromium: `testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/pavel/testing/alpine/AlpineProOutlet.Tests
16 verbose Linux 4.19.141-2-MANJARO
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "t:headless:chromium"
18 verbose node v14.8.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ t:headless:chromium: `testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ t:headless:chromium script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

- and this log was generated when the final part failed to be reported to slack:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 't:headless:chromium' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.7
3 info using node@v14.8.0
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'pret:headless:chromium',
4 verbose run-script   't:headless:chromium',
4 verbose run-script   'postt:headless:chromium'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle @~pret:headless:chromium: @
6 info lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/pavel/testing/alpine/AlpineProOutlet.Tests/node_modules/.bin:/home/pavel/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/pavel/.local/bin:/home/pavel/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin:
9 verbose lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: CWD: /home/pavel/testing/alpine/AlpineProOutlet.Tests
10 silly lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: Args: [ '-c', 'testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~t:headless:chromium: Failed to exec t:headless:chromium script
13 verbose stack Error: @ t:headless:chromium: `testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /home/pavel/testing/alpine/AlpineProOutlet.Tests
16 verbose Linux 4.19.141-2-MANJARO
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "t:headless:chromium"
18 verbose node v14.8.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ t:headless:chromium: `testcafe --test-meta retired=0 "chromium:headless"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ t:headless:chromium script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Yes, they are exactly the same:

```
$ diff 2020-09-04T22_44_57_715Z-debug.log 2020-09-04T22_47_25_555Z-debug.log 
Files 2020-09-04T22_44_57_715Z-debug.log and 2020-09-04T22_47_25_555Z-debug.log are identical
```

The only visual difference I can see is that when the last part doesn't get reported to slack, I don't see:

```
The following message is send to slack: 
 

:checkered_flag: Testing finished at *05/09/2020 00:44:56*
 :stopwatch: Duration: *1m 37s*
 :x: *1/13 failed*
```

in console.

I also tried deleting all node modules from my project (`$ rm -rf node_modules/`) and install everything again (`$ npm install`) with the following `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.0.20",
        "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
        "jest": "^26.1.0",
        "mssql": "^6.2.0",
        "nanoid": "^3.1.9",
        "testcafe": "^1.8.5",
        "testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack": "^1.13.0",
        "testcafe-reporter-html": "^1.4.6",
        "testcafe-reporter-json": "^2.2.0",
        "testcafe-reporter-slack": "git+https://github.com/pavelsaman/testcafe-reporter-slack.git",
        "testcafe-reporter-xunit": "^2.1.0"
    }
```

That didn't help either.

**How can I make sure that the whole report gets reported to my slack channel?** I'd also like to know how else I can debug this to find the root cause. I don't really know where else I can look to find out more.